# Cypher unable to match where not in another collection

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to return items from a collection that aren't in a second collection. I have an example of what I've tried below, but it just returns all items from the first collection.

```
match(e1:Skill) where e1.SkillName = 'skill1' or e1.SkillName = 'skill2'
match(e2:Skill) where e2.SkillName = 'skill2' or e2.SkillName = 'skill3'

match(e1) where 
not e1.SkillName = e2.SkillName

return e1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this part? "I want to return items from a collection that aren't in a second collection."

Comment: To more precise, I don't understand what you mean by "collection"? Is it a list in an attribute, a set of nodes connected by a particular relationship, ...?

Comment: Thanks for helping with this. Basically I want to return the nodes unique to the first match statement.
In my actual application I use 2 multi-step relationship paths to match nodes and need delete a direct relationship to the nodes unique to the first path

Comment: I see - I updated my answer with a new query.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to collect results from one query, and use predicates based on collection membership to find the results you're looking for.

```
match(e2:Skill) 
where e2.SkillName = 'skill2' or e2.SkillName = 'skill3'
with collect(e2) as excluded
match(e1:Skill) 
where (e1.SkillName = 'skill1' or e1.SkillName = 'skill2')
and not e1 in excluded
return e1
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Do not invoke `match(e1)` again, as this will define a new `e1` variable.

Instead, simply add the `where` clause after matching for `e2`:

```
match(e1:Skill) where e1.SkillName = 'skill1' or e1.SkillName = 'skill2'
match(e2:Skill) where e2.SkillName = 'skill2' or e2.SkillName = 'skill3'
where not e1.SkillName = e2.SkillName
return e1
```

You can also simplify your query by using a single `match` and a single `where` clause, and also by using the inequality operator `<>`:

```
match (e1:Skill), (e2:Skill)
where e1.SkillName = 'skill1' or e1.SkillName = 'skill2'
  and e2.SkillName = 'skill2' or e2.SkillName = 'skill3'
  and e1.SkillName <> e2.SkillName
return e1
```

*Update:* if you are looking for nodes that have a unique `SkillName`, then for each node, you can count all nodes with the same `SkillName` and make sure there is only a single one.

```
match (e1:Skill)
where e1.SkillName = 'skill1' or e1.SkillName = 'skill2'
match (e2:Skill {SkillName: e1.SkillName})
with e1, count(e2) AS count
where count = 1
return e1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The simplified query is much more tidy so have implemented it. Unfortunately skill2 is still being returned though when I'd expect only skill1

Comment: I see. For this query, `skill2` is a valid response if there is `skill3` in the database - `e1` will be bound to `skill2` and `e2` will be bound to `skill3`.

Comment: I don't think that will work. An optional match looking for a node of the same label with the same property value of the existing node will at the least return the same node. There's no chance e2 will be null.